# Write a collection of strings to a file using .NET Maui

Tags: c#, .net-maui

In a standard Windows program I will use the following to write a collection of strings to a file....

```
public static async Task ExampleAsync()
{
    string[] lines =
    {
        "First line", "Second line", "Third line" 
    };

    await File.WriteAllLinesAsync("WriteLines.txt", lines);
}
```

How do I do the same thing in a .NET Maui app? I've tried...

```
 await streamWriter.WriteAsync(lines);
```

Comment: StreamWriter/TextWriter does not have a method for writing a collection of strings as lines. But it has methods (and their async counterparts) for writing _a_ line, _WriteLine/Async_. So basically, loop over your string collection/array and write each line with _WriteLine/Async_. However, why would you not use System.IO.File.WriteAllLinesAsync? After all, in your related question, you had no problems using System.IO.File.OpenWrite in your MAUI app...

Answer (score 0):

This solution works:

```
 string targetFileName = "Output1.txt";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("Line 1");
        sb.Append("Line 2");

        // Write the file content to the app data directory
        string targetFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, targetFileName);

        using FileStream outputStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(targetFile);
        using StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream);

        await streamWriter.WriteAsync(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Concering the question, no, that does not work. In your question you demonstrate a code that writes **multiple lines** to a file, and your question asks how to achieve the same in a MAUI app. But your own suggested solution only writes a single line containing the text "Line1Line2". It's totally okay if you are fine with that. But it's not a correct answer to your own question. It would have been a correct answer if you would have used AppendLine instead of Append...